# MLE for censored distributions of the exponential family

Tags: python-3.x, scipy-optimize, mle

With the *scipy.stats* package it is straightforward to fit a distribution to data, e.g. *scipy.stats.expon.fit()* can be used to fit data to an exponential distribution.

However, I am trying to fit data to a censored/conditional distribution in the exponential family. In other words, using MLE, I am trying to find the maximum of

[image],

where [image] is a PDF of a distribution in the exponential family, and [image] is its corresponding CDF.

Mathematically, I have found that the log-likelihood function is convex in the parameter space [image], so my assumption was that it should be relatively straightforward to apply the *scipy.optimize.minimize* function. Notice in the above log-likelihood that by taking [image] we obtain the traditional/uncensored MLE problem.

However, I find that even for simple distributions that e.g. the *nelder-mead* simplex algorithm does not always converge, or that it does converge but the estimated parameters are far off from the true ones. I have attached my code below. Notice that one can choose a distribution, and that the code is generic enough to fit the *loc* and *scale* parameters, as well as the optional *shape* parameters (for e.g. a Beta or Gamma distribution).

My question is: what am I doing wrong to obtain these bad estimates, or sometimes get convergence issues? I have tried a few algorithms but there is not one that easily works, to my surprise as the problem is convex. Are there smoothness issues, and that I need to find a way to use the Jacobian and Hessian in a generic way for this problem?

Are there other methods to tackle this problem? Initially I thought to override *fit()* function in the *scipy.stats.rv* class to take care of the censoring with the CDF, but this seemed quite cumbersome. But since the problem is convex, I would guess that using the minimize function of scipy I should be able to easily get the results...

Comments and help are very welcome!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import expon, gamma, beta, norm
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous as rv


def log_likelihood(func: rv, delays, max_delays=10**8, **func_pars)->float:
    return np.sum(np.log(func.pdf(delays, **func_pars)+1) - np.log(func.cdf(max_delays, **func_pars)))


def minimize_log_likelihood(func: rv, delays, max_delays):

    # Determine number of parameters to estimate (always 'loc', 'scale', sometimes shape parameters)
    n_pars = 2 + func.numargs

    # Initialize guess (loc, scale, [shapes])
    x0 = np.ones(n_pars)

    def wrapper(params, *args):
        func = args[0]
        delays = args[1]
        max_delays = args[2]
        loc, scale = params[0], params[1]

        # Set 'loc' and 'scale' parameters
        kwargs = {'loc': loc, 'scale': scale}

        # Add shape parameters if existing to kwargs
        if func.shapes is not None:
            for i, s in enumerate(func.shapes.split(', ')):
                kwargs[s] = params[2+i]
        
        return -log_likelihood(func=func, delays=delays, max_delays=max_delays, **kwargs)

    # Find maximum of log-likelihood (thus minimum of minus log-likelihood; see wrapper function)
    return minimize(wrapper, x0, args=(func, delays, max_delays), options={'disp': True}, 
                    method='nelder-mead', tol=1e-8)




# Test code with by sampling from known distribution, and retrieve parameters
distribution = expon
dist_pars = {'loc': 0, 'scale': 4}
x = np.linspace(distribution.ppf(0.0001, **dist_pars), distribution.ppf(0.9999, **dist_pars), 1000)

res = minimize_log_likelihood(distribution, x, 10**8)
print(res)
```

Comment: As an additional comment: it is in general very difficult to fit the location parameters using MLE. Keeping the 'loc' parameter fixed solved all my issues, and since the above problem is convex, I now indeed get the correct solutions for pretty much arbitrary initial values x0.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the convergence is bad due to numerical inaccuracies. Best is to replace

```
np.log(func.pdf(x, **func_kwargs))
```

with

```
func.logpdf(x, **func_kwargs)
```

This leads to correct estimation of the parameters. The same holds for the CDF. The documentation of *scipy* also indicates that the numerical accuracy of the latter performs better.

This all works nicely with the Exponential, Normal, Gamma, chi2 distributions. The Beta distribution still gives me issues, but I think this is again to some (other) numerical inaccuracies which I will analyse separately.